# How to turn procedural skin normal map => image texture

Tags: materials, export, texture-baking, baking

I have I procedural skin shader (applied to a human character mesh) with a couple of voronoi nodes that I connect to the 'normal' of the Principled BSDF shader which is cool, but I was thinking if it's possible to turn the generated bump/normals into a proper normal map so I can export to Godot?

I looked up some guides on "baking" textures but i can't seem to be able to do it.

Basically, I just want to tell blender: Hey that Bump node? take the output of it and create an 4k image texture with this UVmap for me.

[image: showing the bump setup in shader editor]

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is plug your texture directly into the *Base Color* of the *Principled BSDF* (or even into the *Output* node), create an *Image Texture* with a new image, keep this node selected, make sure that the unwrap of your object is correct, then in the *Bake* panel choose *Bake Type > Diffuse*, uncheck *Contributions > Direct* and *Indirect* and bake:

[image]

It's not clear if you want a bump map or a normal map, as Tsybe says "in case you want to bake a normal map, you can just leave the nodes connected to the *Normal* socket and set the *Bake Type* to *Normal*".

Comment: In case you want to bake a normal map, you can just leave the nodes connected to the "Normal" socket and set the Bake Type to "Normal".

Comment: @Tsybe Oh yes of course thanks I'll edit

Comment: @Tysbe when I set bake type to 'normal' and then select the new image in the shader editor and bake, it bakes an empty blue normal map to the diffuse skin texture :\ Maybe disconnect the diffuse?

Comment: The other approach didn't work either - the image is saved over my skin diffuse image - not the new blank image (I have the new image selected in the shader editor). Also the resulting image looks wrong.

Comment: @PetterThowsen It's hard to say what is the reason behind it. If you could share the blend file, we'll take a look at it. https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Or if you could just share some images about the process and the bake settings

Answer (score 0):

Clearly feeding black and white data into a Normal socket won't result in anything. If you want to bake your Bump as NormalMap you need to connect your data to "Emission" socket (bc it will not interpolate your data) and bake as "Emit". Then you duplicate your object, you add Subdivision Surface (will surely need more than 2 subdiv). Then you add a Displace modifier and use your baked Bump texture. Then you proceed with the Selected to Active baking workflow using your displaced object as a High Poly